# String index out of range inside while condition

Tags: java

I'm having an error with this line of code: while(s.charAt(i - 1) != '\0').
I'm trying to compare the input string using switch and here's the entire code:

```
public static int Main()
{
String s = new String(new char[20]);
byte c;
int state = 0;
int i = 0;

System.out.print("\n Enter a string:");
s = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
while (s.charAt(i - 1) != '\0')
{
         char result = s.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(result);

 switch (state)
 {
 case 0:
     c = (byte) s.charAt(i++);
 if (c == (byte)'a')
 {
 state = 1;
 }
 else if (c == (byte)'b')
 {
 state = 2;
 }
 else
 {
 state = 6;
 }
 break;
 case 1:
     c = (byte) s.charAt(i++);
 if (c == (byte)'a')
 {
 state = 3;
 }

 else if (c == (byte)'b')
 {
 state = 4;
 }
else
{
 state = 6;
}
 break;
 case 2:
     c = (byte) s.charAt(i++);
 if (c == (byte)'a')
 {
 state = 6;
 }
 else if (c == (byte)'b')
 {
 state = 2;
 }
else
{
 state = 6;
}
 break;
 case 3:
     c = (byte) s.charAt(i++);
 if (c == (byte)'a')
 {
 state = 3;
 }
 else if (c == (byte)'b')
 {
 state = 2;
 }
else
{
 state = 6;
}
 break;
 case 4:
     c = (byte) s.charAt(i++);
 if (c == (byte)'a')
 {
 state = 6;
 }

 else if (c == (byte)'b')
 {
 state = 5;
 }
else
{
 state = 6;
}
 break;
 case 5:
     c = (byte) s.charAt(i++);
 if (c == (byte)'a')
 {
 state = 6;
 }
 else if (c == (byte)'b')
 {
 state = 2;
 }
else
{
 state = 6;
}
 break;
 case 6:
     System.out.printf("\n %s is not recognised.",s);
 System.exit(0);
 }
}

if (state == 1)
{
 System.out.printf("\n %s is accepted under rule 'a'",s);
}
 else if ((state == 2) || (state == 4))
 {
System.out.printf("\n %s is accepted under rule 'a*b+'",s);
 }
 else if (state == 5)
 {
 System.out.printf("\n %s is accepted under rule 'abb'",s);
 }
        return 0;
```

}

It says String index out of range. I've also try to display the charAt(i) it displays the correct string but I don't know why I'm having this error

Comment: `i` != `i-1` . (1 more to go)

Comment: At least you should try to debug your code first...?

Answer (score 0):

you are using `int i = 0;` and then checking `while (s.charAt(i-1) != '\0')`. when you set `i` to `0`, `i-1` would be `-1` and `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`
will occur. so either use `int i = 1;` or `while (s.charAt(i) != '\0')`